# 400 - Bad Request Error when using SXA search bar in preview mode

Tags: sxa

I am testing the search functionnality in SXA.

For this, I have just added a Search Box with default datasource and default fields and a Search Result all with default also to my page.

When I'm typing something in the search bar in preview mode, I get a 400 GET (Bad Request) message in console and in log,

```
5920 17:25:46 ERROR Could not resolve type name: 
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Pipelines.TranslateQuery.AnalyticsContextResolver, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
5920 17:25:46 WARN  Results endpoint exception
Exception: System.Exception


Message: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.Pipelines.TranslateQuery.AnalyticsContextResolver, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
Source: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   à Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.Raise(String error, String method)
   à Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateType(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   à Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   à Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   à Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   à Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode)
   à Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode)
   à Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters)
   à Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   à Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   à Sitecore.Abstractions.CorePipelineWrapper.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args)
   à Sitecore.ContentSearch.Pipelines.TranslateQuery.TranslateQueryPipeline.Run(ICorePipeline pipeline, TranslateQueryArgs args)
   à Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.QueryBuilder.CreateQuery[T](IProviderSearchContext context, IEnumerable`1 searchStringModel, Item startLocationItem, IEnumerable`1 additionalContexts)
   à Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.QueryBuilder.CreateQuery[T](IProviderSearchContext context, IEnumerable`1 searchStringModel)
   à Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetQuery(String query, String scope, String language, Coordinates center, String& indexName)
   à Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetResults(String v, String q, String s, String l, String g, String n, String o, Int32 e, Int32 p, String sig)
```

So I guess parameters should be wrong, but according to tutorials I read, you can set basic search with no further coding or configuration... Where am I wrong ? What should I do to make this work ?

Comment: I would say that's not because of wrong search query but there might be something wrong with your indexes configuration. Ensure that all of the indexes which are patched in SXA search provider config really exists. Are you using Lucene or Solr? Can you also provide your query with all of the params?

Comment: Can you verify that Sitecore.ContentSearch.Analytics.dll is in your bin folder?

Comment: Indeed, dlls were present but with version 1.0... so I replaced them, now I don't get errors anymore but I don't get any search results either when I type a page's title or part of its page content field in the search field